# Scheme open source projects?

Tags: scheme

I'm learning scheme and was wondering if there are any active open-source projects I might be able to get involved in?

I'm nearing the end of SICP and although this has good complex examples no textbook code compares to real-world applications. eg testing code / benchmarking / revision control styles / sheer size and scope etc. Hence my curiousity at seeing a project in the wild.

I tried searching google code but only found projects that are interpreters that implement RSR5/6.

Perhaps there are not many projects out there and I should consider scala?!

Advice or even pointers to specific projects appreciated.

Update: wasn't clear that I'd prefer to work on a project written +in+ scheme rather than an implementation +of+ scheme.

Update 2: there are also some projects on [github](http://github.com/languages/Scheme). Not many, but some.

Comment: Well, I'm amazed that there appear to be nearly as many implementations than open source projects written +in+ scheme. I'll keep this open a tiny bit longer in case someone rides to the rescue...

Comment: "I'm more curious to see how people construct medium to large scale projects +in+ scheme."
No one does, because it's an impenetrable language beyond illustrative and theory-oriented programming. Large applications would be nearly impossible to maintain because of its dependence on recursion, which can be hard to read if you weren't the original programmer and even harder to figure out how to change the business logic (the actual getting shit done part of the code) without screwing up other things. Learn python instead; it's actually useful, or C++ if you want to contribute to open source effor

Answer (score 3):

Currently SourceForge claims to have [293 projects](http://sourceforge.net/search/?&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A242) written in Scheme. You should be able to find something in there that is of interest.

Comment: Thanks for reyplying. Yes, seen this. But if you order by "last updated" only the top 20 have been updated since 2008 and the majority of these are implementations of scheme, not projects that happen to be written +in+ scheme.

Comment: I should add I did look on sourceforge first but wondered if the scheme community kept their projects in another sink that I didn't know about. As I'm sure you have found - googling for "scheme" with words like project produces answers across many domains.

Comment: So...find one that interests you, take a look at the code, and if it strikes your fancy either fork the project or get in touch with the maintainer (possibly have the project transfered to you).

Comment: Agreed. You are just not going to find *that* many projects written in scheme these days. So pick one that interests you and run with it.

Comment: I already said I'd looked on SF, thanks. I just wondered if there were other scheme project repositories, and I guess not. Ah well, no harm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at schemers.org. The [implementation](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations) page has a large number of scheme implementations. Many of these are open source would welcome volunteers.

Comment: although I am interested in scheme implementations I'm more curious to see how people construct medium to large scale projects +in+ scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning scheme. Read "Little Schemer" and wanted to try some real code. One small step to is to try writing GnuCash reports. Not really an open source project, but give something to try scheme in real life. This will also help to learn about GUILE which is official extension language for GNU operating system.